# On div scroll activate another div's scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUySq/1/)

I trying to activate my current scroll while I am outside that scroll, specifically in `#DivDet`

here is what I tried:

```
$("div#DivDet").scroll(function () {
    // I don't know what i should have here      
    // something like $("div#scrlDiv").scroll();
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom scrollbar?

Comment: @WooCaSh I don't expect 'finished' solution, I specifically pointed what I need.If you can't help no need to hassle.

Comment: @undefined yes I am working on custom one.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It sounds like you want to respond to a scroll on one `div` by scrolling another.

You've already determined how to hook the `scroll` event. To set the scroll position of an element (the other `div`), you set the element's `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` values (which are in pixels). If you want two divs to scroll in near-unison, for instance, you'd assign the source div's `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` to the target `div`.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/uhozam/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uhozam/1/edit)

Relevant JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var target = $("#target");
  $("#source").scroll(function() {
    target.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
          .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
  });
})();
```

or alternately ([source](http://jsbin.com/uhozam/2/edit)):

```
(function() {
  var target = $("#target")[0]; // <== Getting raw element
  $("#source").scroll(function() {
    target.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    target.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
  });
})();
```

Full page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Scroll Example</title>
  <style>
    .scroll-example {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 40%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-right: 20px;
      height: 100px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Scroll the left div, watch the right one.</p>
  <div id="source" class="scroll-example">
    1
    <br>2
    <br>3
    <br>4
    <br>5
    <br>6
    <br>7
    <br>8
    <br>9
    <br>10
    <br>11
    <br>12
    <br>13
    <br>14
    <br>15
    <br>16
    <br>17
    <br>18
    <br>19
    <br>20
  </div>
  <div id="target" class="scroll-example">
    1
    <br>2
    <br>3
    <br>4
    <br>5
    <br>6
    <br>7
    <br>8
    <br>9
    <br>10
    <br>11
    <br>12
    <br>13
    <br>14
    <br>15
    <br>16
    <br>17
    <br>18
    <br>19
    <br>20
  </div>
  <script>
  (function() {
    var target = $("#target");
    $("#source").scroll(function() {
      target.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
            .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
    });
  })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excuse me but I am new to javascript / jquery. I am wondering if there is a way to start from the bottom of the first scrollable div and to start from the top of the second scrollable div. With a few word to create a reversing scrolling effect. If you can help me or give me some hints how that can be done I will be really grateful.

Comment: T.J. - You're literally a rock star, thank you so much for posting this almost 4 years ago!

Comment: In IE, 2 div scoll not equal.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution with Vanilla JavaScript**

```js
const multiElementScroll = ( elem1, elem2 ) => {
  elem1.onscroll = function() {
    elem2.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
  };
}

multiElementScroll( div1, div2 )
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.scroll-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #d99;
}

.scroll-box h2 { margin-top: 50px; }
```

```html
<section>
<div class="scroll-box" id="div1"> 
  <h1>A</h1>
  <h2>B</h2>
  <h2>C</h2>
  <h2>D</h2>
  <h2>E</h2>
  <h2>F</h2>
  <h2>G</h2>
  <h2>H</h2>
</div>

<div class="scroll-box" id="div2"> 
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h2>2</h2>
  <h2>3</h2>
  <h2>4</h2>
  <h2>5</h2>
</div>
<section>
```