# How to scroll two forms synchronously using Django form?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, html

I'm using django form and it's defined like this:

```
class SrtForm(forms.Form):
text = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 200}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SrtForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['text'].label = ''
```

Then I use it in html like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form en_form %}
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
     <form action="{% url 'edit_space:edit_srt' video_id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form zh_form %}
        {% if task_status == 'taken_by_me' %}
            {% buttons %}
                <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit changes</button>
            {% endbuttons %}
        {% endif %}
    </form>
</div>
```

Then I got two forms shown 50/50 at the same row. Like this:
[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Dee.png)

Each form has its own scrollbar. What I want to achieve is when I drag one of the two scrollbars, the other side scrolls synchronously. Is there any way to do that in django form in detail?

Any answers would be appreciated. :)

Comment: short answer, yes

Comment: don't think so, django just renders the form from there you'd need javascript.

Comment: This has nothing to do  with django. See and example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376794/on-div-scroll-activate-another-divs-scroll